# Homework question on quadratic forms and change of coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

I have been given the following question (on a homework):

i) Write down the symmetric matrix A corresponding to the quadratic form $q(v)= wz-xy$ in the 4 variables $w,x,y,z$.

I have the matrix A = $$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 \\
        0 & 0 & -0.5 & 0 \\
        0 & -0.5 & 0 & 0 \\
        0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

ii) Find a change of coordinates to transform $q$ to the form $aw_1^2 + bx_1^2 + cy_1^2 + dz_1^2$.

This is where it all falls apart for me. I can only find examples for how to do this with 3x3 matrices and so I am really confused. If anyone would be willing to give me an example, or lead me in the correct direction I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $w_1 = w+z$, $z_1=w-z$, $x_1=x+y$, $y_1=x-y$, because $wz = \frac 14(w_1^2-z_1^2)$, and $xy= \frac 14(x_1^2-y_1^2)$. Hence your quadratic forms will be $q=\frac 14 (w_1^2-x_1^2+y_1^2-z_1^2)$.

Comment: Thank you, so I can see exactly why these numbers work, but just out of curiosity, is this the way we should always do it? Is there a specific method that you followed to find these?

Comment: Also, could you verify that this is the correct change of coordinates matrix:

Comment: $$
        \begin{matrix}
        0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 \\
        0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 \\
        0 & 0.5 & -0.5 & 0 \\
        0.5 & 0 & 0 & -0.5 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: Yes, I followed a standard algorithm for transforming quadratic forms into their canonical form. Your matrix is correct after the editing.

Comment: Sorry, just edited it after realising my mistake! Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. You can approve my answer in that case.